# SSH Jump Host via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh

I have the following environment configuration:

Client -> HOST_A (public IP address) -> HOST_B (private IP address)

That being said, to avoid connecting manually to HOST_A and then to HOST_B, I'm using the jump host configuration below in the .ssh/config file.

```
Host HOST_B
  ProxyCommand ssh -q HOST_A nc -q0 HOST_B 22
```

This solution works well when I'm using a regular terminal, but it doesn't work when using "Remote Systems" in Eclipse IDE. I'm not sure if I have to enforce the config file or how to configure jump hosts in Eclipse.

**Does anyone have an idea how to sort this out in Eclipse?**

Answer (score 0):

What about an ssh tunnel?

```
ssh -L 2222:HOST_B:22 -N HOST_A
```

Then you can use localhost:2222 to connect to HOST_B with ssh. You just need Eclipse to allow you to specify a port in the ssh configuration.

Comment: I'd like some configuration on Eclipse instead of running that command on Terminal every time and then having the IDE connecting to the server.